# Bottom tab bar pushed off bottom of screen until touch event

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an app where fragments are switched in and out of the screen using a bottom tab bar.  One of those fragments is made full screen using

```
getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
```

and that is undone when you leave that fragment.

The problem is that when you leave that fragment and switch to another one, the bottom tab bar drops about halfway off the screen, until a touch event is registered, and then it jumps back to where it's supposed to be.  It works fine in the full screen fragment, and fine after the touch event, it's just when you switch away from the full screen fragment, it goes about halfway off the screen.

I am not able to post the code as it is proprietary, but if there are any questions, I can do my best to answer them.

I should note that this issue does not happen on Android Q (API 29), regardless of device.

Comment: What do you have in your `onResume` function of your fragments?

Comment: for non-fullscreen fragments:
window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

As soon as you touch the screen, everything behaves as it should, but before that the bar is covered by the bottom of the phone screen, or the system navigation bar, depending on the device.

Comment: try calling `requestLayout()` on the (parent) view...

Comment: I've tried that before, just tried it again to make sure and it didn't work.  If it helps, this issue is not happening on Android Q, regardless of device.  For example, the issue appears on a Pixel 3XL running API 28, but on one running 29, everything is fine